Rest template not adding Content-Length header for empty body resulting in '411 Length Required' post spring boot upgrade to 3.2.5
Pretty much the title.
We upgraded spring boot from 3.1.x to 3.2.5 and we see the behavior of Rest template has been changed.
For a POST request with empty body, the rest template is not adding the header Content-Length with value 0.
What's worse? Despite adding it explicitly to the headers, Rest template is discarding it for some reason.
This is causing the server to throw Http 411 Length Required.
Following are the before and after logs for the same.
The logs are from the logger DEBUG - o.a.h.c.h.i.Wire.wire(92) - http-outgoing-0 
From spring boot 3.1.10

---- >> "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Authorization: Basic ******=[\r][\n]"
---- >> "grant_type: client_credentials[\r][\n]"
---- >> "scope: you don't need this[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Content-Length: 0[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Host: this one too[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
---- >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.1 (Java/17.0.10)[\r][\n]"
---- >> "[\r][\n]"

After spring upgrade::
From spring boot 3.2.5

---- >> "POST /oauth2/token HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Accept: text/plain, application/json, application/*+json, */*[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Authorization: Basic ****=[\r][\n]"
---- >> "grant_type: client_credentials[\r][\n]"
---- >> "scope: you don't need this[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, x-gzip, deflate[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Host: this one too[\r][\n]"
---- >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]"
---- >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/5.2.1 (Java/17.0.10)[\r][\n]"

I don't see anything related to this change mentioned in the 3.2 release notes.
How do I fix this now? When the client discards the length header despite adding it explicitly?
Minimum reproducible problem:: repository. I have added logs that demonstrate behavior of Content-Length being present/absent.
EDIT
One hack I am looking at is setting the POST body as empty string.

might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77658440/springboot-3-2-0-custom-resttemplate-doesnt-send-content-length

Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

@GeorgiiLvov Thanks. But it is not working anymore with Boot 3.2.5

@aled added Minimum reproducible problem

@ArunGowda, I would recommend to read this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/32678

@GeorgiiLvov I already did. They are fixing it in spring 6.1.7 and boot 3.2.6. Did I miss any potential solutions from that page?

I just noticed this after upgrade to spring boot 3.2.5 when calling google recaptcha, since its a post with no body, the tokens are url params

It must be fixed now in 3.2.6 @andrewps. we had to downgrade to 3.1.11 back then.

Yeah, i upgraded to 3.3.1 and it was fixed
